# What are the various forms of Vishnu according to Pancharatra?

Tags: vishnu, philosophy, pancharatra

Recently while reading Prasthana Bheda of Madhusudan Sarasvati, I found he mentioned four forms of Vishnu according to Pancharatra:

Quoting from [sanskritdocuments.org](https://sanskritdocuments.org/sites/snsastri/PrasthAnabheda-Engl.pdf):

> एवं वैष्णवं नारदादिभिः कृतं **पञ्चरात्रम्** । तत्र
>   **वासुदेवसंकर्षणप्रद्युम्नानिरुद्धाश्चत्वारः पदार्था निरूपिताः** ।
>   भगवान्वासुदेवः सर्वकारणं परमेश्वरः । तस्मादुत्पद्यते
>   संकर्षणाख्यो जीवः । तस्मान्मनः प्रद्युम्नस्तस्मादनिरुद्धोऽहंकारः ।
>   सर्वे चैते भगवतो वासुदेवस्यैवांशभूताः । तदभिन्ना
>   एवेति भगवतो वासुदेवस्य मनोवाक्कायवृत्तिभिराराधनं कृत्वा
>   कृतकृत्यो भवतीत्यादि च निरूपितम् ।
>
> **pancarAtram**,  the  vaiShNava  shAstram,  was  composed  by  nArada  and 
>   others. In   it **four   entities,   vAsudeva,   sankarShaNa,   pradyumna   and aniruddha  are  mentioned**.  bhagavAn  vAsudeva  is  the  supreme  Lord  and 
>   the   cause   of   everything.   From   Him   emanates   the   jIva   known   as sankarShaNa.   From   him   pradyumna,   the   mind.   From   him  emanates ahamkAra  known as  aniruddha. All  these    are  part - incarnations  of  Lord vAsudeva  Himself  and  non - different  from  Him  and  so  it  is  said  that  one becomes fulfilled by devoting the mind, speech and body to the worship of bhagavAn vAsudeva.

Though the work of Madhusudana Sarasvati describe a bit what those four forms are, I want to know and understand from the Pancharatra texts. Besides, while discussing with Keshav Srinivasan, I found that the four forms mentioned by Madhusudana Sarasvati are actually part of one category of forms called **Vyuha** and the other categories of forms are **Para, Vibhava, Antaryami, and Archa.**

Hence, I want to know what are the various forms of Vishnu according to Pancharatra? (Quote Pancharatra texts in your answer)

Answer (score 3):

As per *Sātvata saṁhitā*, these are the various forms of *Bhagavāna Viṣṇu*

The 4 *vyuha* forms - *Vāsudeva*, *Pradyumna*, *Aniruddha* & *Saṅkarṣaṇa*

The  38 *vibhava* forms - *Padmanābha*, *Dhruva*, *Ananta*, *Śaktyātmā*, *Madhusūdana*, *Vidyādhideva*, *Kapila*, *Viśvarūpa*, *Haṁsa*, *Varāha*, *Vaṛavānala*, *Dharma*, *Hayagriva*, *Ekarnavaśayī*, *Kūrma*, *Ekaśṛgī*, *Nṛsiṁha*, *Amṛtāharaṇa*, *Śrīpati*,  *Kāntātma*, *Rāhujit*, *Kālanemighna*, *Pārijātahara*, *Lokanātha*, *Dattātreya*, *Vatapatrashāyī*, *Matsya*, *Vāmana*, *Trivikrama*, *Nara*, *Nārāyaṇa*, *Hari*, *Kṛṣṇa*, *Paraśurāma*, *Rāmacandra*, *Vedavyasa*, *Kalki* & *Pātālaśāyī*,

*Arcā* is the term used to denote an icon. It is of the following types - *cala* or movable one (for example the *utsavamūrti*, *snāpanamūrti* & *bhogamūrti*), *acala* or the immovable one (for example the collosal ones made of stone that remain fixed within the *garbhagṛha*), permanent ones (like idols made of stone, metal, wood), temporary ones (like idols made of clay & paintings), those with supernatural origins (like *śālagrāmaśilā*s), those consecrated by *siddha*s & those consecrated by ordinary mortals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer can you provide location of verse from Satva Samhita for reference?